# Debugging macro with the help of gdb

Tags: c++, macros, gdb

I know the that the alternative approach is to convert the macro to inline function which will allow the gdb to step into it.

But I want to know if there is any way by which I can debug through each line of a macro definition by using gdb like any other function.

e.g. in the below code snippet.

```
#define print_macro printf("We're inside the macro now");\
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) \
     { \
          if(i%2 == 0) \
              printf("%d is even number", i); \
          else \
              printf("%d is odd number);\
     }

int main()
{
    print_macro;
    return 0;
}
```

In the gdb prompt can we break in main and then step into `print_macro` and go through each line of it's definition one by one by using `next`

Comment: Since you are already into debugging, the print_macro has already been replaced with the corresponding value of it. There is no more existence of print_macro once your program is compiled and running.

Comment: the debug prints should work but the debugger can't distinguish lines in the macro from lines in the source code before macro expansion. Hypothetically it could be smart enough but why bother supporting that when macros are bad practice. Replace the macro with an actual function until you have it working.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the gdb commands:

```
gdb> macro expand *expression using macros*
gdb> info macro *macro name*
```

Depending on you g++ version, you may need to add -ggdb3 to the compile command.

If a macro is defined multiple times, `info macro` will by default show the one that applies at the current location. `info macro -all ...` lists the possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The debugging difficulty is one of the reasons why macros should be avoided. No, you cannot debug macro commands line by line, you can not set breakpoint in macro, you can not see variables values in the macro etc. The reasons for this are at least two:

**Technical**. The compiler doesn't know anything about macros expansion at all. All macros are expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler is called. The compiler will not be able to add debugging information for addressing macro lines, compiler doesn't have it! So debugger can only assume how exactly the preprocessor performs macro expansion.

**Logical**. The output C++ code command does not necessarily correspond to one line of (one) macro. Structurally and syntactically, the macro code may absolutely not be like C++ code. Such line by line macro debugging seems logical only for simple examples like yours where the resulting C++ code is easily viewed (easily for you, not for debugger!). But consider a more convoluted example. At what line debugger should indicate in this example? I think `ASSIGN(VAR(INT, i), 10);` the only logical option.

```
#define INT int
#define VAR(TYPE, NAME)  TYPE NAME
#define ASSIGN(V, VAL) V = VAL

ASSIGN(VAR(INT, i), 10);
```

You cannot debug macros as С++ code since they are not directly С++ code! However, you can expand a macro for debugging as advised. If you need flexibility like macros but without debugging problems, use template functions.

Comment: @NikosC. I think this is not what the questioner is talking about. Of course, we can expand the macro code (with certain limitations) to C++ code and then debug it. But this is debugging of the final C++ code, not a macro. In addition, the debugger only predicts the behavior of the preprocessor. This does not always work as expected (as stated in the documentation). For example, debugger knows nothing about  used compilation flags, which breaks easily the logic of macro expansion

Answer (score 0):

You can't step through macros but you can use the `-E` flag to see what the macros expand to:

```
g++ main.cpp -E | less
```